# Advice on the best project type to use for an RSS reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, rss

So this is more of an advice question.

We have a project that involves an RSS feed and the reports from the feed being saved to a database. This will need to have a Job service so either quartz or chron.

My question is that there are many types of project that we use as developers but in my line of work these are normally web API with MVC hooked up to an angular front end.

With this project we do not need any end points so no need for MVC. Just after some advice as to what others would recommend.

The flow will be 
1. c# call to rss feed with a parameter (5 per second max)
2. xml returned
3. xml mapped to a DTO/Modal
4. DTO/modal saved to Database
5. External reporting tool will handle data.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a console application for the following reasons:

1. Requirement for a job.  Console apps can easily be ran via scheduled tasks/jobs.
2. Lack of requirement for User Interface.  Perhaps you might need to pass in a few parameters, not sure.  Perfect for a console application.
3. The requirements for retrieving and storing of the rss feeds XML can all be handled in C#, nothing special needed from a framework perspective that the console app can't easily do.

Comment: These were my original thoughts, Although thought it best to check in case I over plumb it.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider a **windows service project**.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIAWC.jpg

1. Make it a purely background process.
2. You don’t have to worry about console windows appearing in a user session and taking measures to keep it hidden.
3. There are few operational tasks - like managing the service through service management console, out of box support for logon and failure recovery etc. which can be leveraged too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will have a look into this also. I'm guessing on the server you could use windows scheduler to run the service automatically every Saturday at a specific time? some people mention its better to have a console app triggered by windows scheduler rather than to have the service running indefinitely.

Comment: This would require more work and isn't schedulable via scheduler.... and it's trivial to hide the console window especially in scheduled tasks.

Comment: Agreed on it will require more work and can't be scheduled on windows scheduler. Though, a windows service can own both responsibilities of scheduling and execution as a self-contained entity. This can be packaged in an installer and installed on various deployments. It depends on what are the project requirements. From effort standpoint, console app will do the work. Thanks for commenting!